# Report Viewer not loaded dynamically

Tags: asp.net, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I am binding the value to report viewer dynamically.

While click on the button I will get the datatable. So I added the datatable in xsd.

In xsd datatable also I inserted the record correctly.

Al last I got the error

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'OnReportLoaded': object is null or undefined**

Please help me in this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and placing the ReportViewer control in an Update Panel corrected:

Patrick

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
    <Triggers > 
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGetReport" />
    </Triggers> 
    <ContentTemplate> 

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReportViewer" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetReport" runat="server" Text="Submit"     onclick="btnGetReport_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```